# How to write a Buffer to a Buffer

Tags: node.js

Now do I write a Buffer into another Buffer at some offset?

We can do [`buf.write(string, offset)`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_write_string_offset_length_encoding), but this only works for strings. I'd like to write `buf.write(sourceBuf, offset)`, but this throws an error: `TypeError: Argument must be a string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`buf.copy`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_copy_target_targetstart_sourcestart_sourceend) function:

```
sourceBuf.copy(buf, offset)
```

This copies `sourceBuf` into `buf` at byte `offset`, or into the beginning of `buf` if `offset` is omitted.

The full syntax is:

```
sourceBuf.copy(target[, targetStart[, sourceStart[, sourceEnd]]])
```